# Using Panda to skip the next three rows from a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on this code forever:
I would like to accomplish the following
-If Pout>3 then drop/delete the next 3 Rows

```
df=pd.read_csv(file,sep=',',usecols=['Iin', 'Iout','Pout'])
print(df['Pout'])
for i in df['Pout']:
   if i>3:
      df.drop(df[3:])# drop/delete the next 3 rows regardless of the value
 print(df)
```

Any help will greatly appreciated

Thanks

I came up with this code based on your first code. but the updated version that  you have just posted is more efficient. I am now dropping the next five rows after the conditions have been met.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,5.0,1,2.3,2.1,2,1,3,4,7], 'b': 
[1,4,0.2,4.5,8.2,1,2,3,4,7], 'c': [1,4.5,5.4,6,2,4,2,3,4,7]})
for index in range(len(df['c'])):
  if df['c'][index] >3:
    df.at[index+1, 'c'] = None
    df.at[index+2, 'c'] = None
    df.at[index+3, 'c'] = None 
    df.at[index+4, 'c'] = None
    df.at[index+5, 'c'] = None
    print(df['c'])
    break
```

Comment: clarification-- when the condition is met (if i>3) delete/skip the next three rows. this deletion should happen only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,5,1,2,2,2,1], 'b': [1,4,2,4,8,1,2], 'c': [1,2,6,6,2,1,2]})
for i in df['c']:
   if i>3:
      try:
         idx = df['c'].tolist().index(i)# drop/delete the next 3 rows regardless of the value
         print(idx)
      except:
         pass
      for i in range(idx, idx+3):
         df.at[i, 'c'] = None
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1.0
1  5  4  2.0
2  1  2  NaN
3  2  4  NaN
4  2  8  NaN
5  2  1  1.0
6  1  2  2.0
```

my solution is with a dummy data frame

i got the index of the item if the item is bigger than 3 then iterate trough the range of the items index to the items index plus 3 then do `at` function to set the value to `Nan`

In my edit i just added try and except and now it works

**For 5 rows:**

I think this code is what you want, i also think this is more efficient

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,5.0,1,2.3,2.1,2,1,3,4,7], 'b': 
[1,4,0.2,4.5,8.2,1,2,3,4,7], 'c': [1,4.5,5.4,6,2,4,2,3,4,7]})
for index in range(len(df['c'])):
  if df['c'][index] >3:
     for i in range(index+1, index+6):
         df.at[i, 'c'] = None
     print(df['c'])
     break
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    4.5
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    3.0
8    4.0
9    7.0
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Comment: your answer works if column 'a' is chosen, but it does not work when 'b' is chosen. by any means it is an excellent starting point. I get this error ----------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-21cf327fe82c> in <module>()
      3 for i in df['b']:
      4    if i>3:
----> 5       idx = df['b'].tolist().index(i)# drop/delete the next 3 rows regardless of the value
      6       for i in range(idx, idx+5):
      7          df.at[i, 'b'] = None
ValueError: 4 is not in list

Comment: @MeraLouder did you try my new solution?

Comment: just saw your post. came up with a solution but yours is more efficient                                      import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,5.0,1,2.3,2.1,2,1,3,4,7], 'b': [1,4,0.2,4.5,8.2,1,2,3,4,7], 'c': [1,4.5,5.4,6,2,4,2,3,4,7]})
for index in range(len(df['c'])):
    if df['c'][index] >3:
        df.at[index+1, 'c'] = None
        df.at[index+2, 'c'] = None
        df.at[index+3, 'c'] = None 
        df.at[index+4, 'c'] = None
        df.at[index+5, 'c'] = None
        print(df['c'])
        break

Comment: @MeraLouder I just did try and except because i see that it actually the  code still goes it doesn't break i know that because i printed something after the line that breaks, but it still prints it

Comment: @U-Forward please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: @MeraLouder I know you need to have more than 15 reputation to up vote,but if it's your own question you can up vote even if you have less than 15 reputation

Comment: @MeraLouder Oh yeah, You where right, actually even if it's your own question you still can't upvote